# How can I unset Ctrl+L in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

I am trying a very simple thing. I have a neovim config in which I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for something. In PowerShell it's already mapped to the `clear` command.

How can I unset this keybind? I am very habitual to writing `clear` every time I want to clear terminal anyway.

Comment: Did my answer help @VipulRajan? If so, please use the website properly and mark it as a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can unset any keybinding that you want by executing this command:

```
Remove-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord ctrl+l
```

Note that the case of the keys matters and if you paste it in a console window it will only remove the binding temporarily.

For it to work permamently, you need to add it to profile. Profile files have different locations with different PowerShell versions, to find out where is yours, use `echo $PROFILE`. Open that file and insert the above line anywhere.